# Map code-behind tag as a duplicate tag of codebehind

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The [code-behind](/questions/tagged/code-behind) tag is a duplicate of [codebehind](/questions/tagged/codebehind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed. Since the term is hyphenated in (most?) official documents, I've opted for the hyphenated tag to be the master tag.

Comment: the tag wiki was more complete for `codebehind`, which was why I assumed `codebehind` was probably the canonical version.

Comment: I noticed, but even in the tag wiki the term is hyphenated too. I've restored the tag wiki onto the hyphenated tag.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! I'll accept this in about 5 minutes.

Comment: No problem - I'd happened to drop by on meta and notice your request 1 minute after it was posted.